# Adding a comments feature for a Project in djangorestframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created a project API in djangorestframework but I want to add a comments feature in it also. I was scratching my head thinking how can I do it but couldn't end up with a solution since I'm a beginner in djangorestframework.

here is my models.py:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    header_image = models.ImageField(default="default.jpg")
    demo = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    code = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and here is my serializers.py:

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = "__all__"
```

and here is my views.py:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def getProjects(request):
    project = models.Project.objects.all()
    serializer = ProjectSerializer(project, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Please help me in showing how can I add a comments section to the project API

note: I don't want the comments API to be a different object instead it should be a nested object in the object of the project

Comment: You mean you don't want to use FK relation ?

Comment: @Amin not like that i just want the feature of comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As each project can have several comments, you should implement `Comment` model and make a FK between these two

**models.py**

```py
...

class Comment(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    ... # Some other field if you want. like created_time, author, ...
```

Then you can have a nested serializer to get comments with project:

**serializers.py**

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('text', ...)


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = (..., 'comments')
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Amin but I found a bug in the model that you wrote in the `Text = models.Textfield(null=False, blank=Flase)` pls change the `Flase` to `False`